# image src getting updated after closing tag

Tags: jquery

i am trying to update image src from text input on keyup or copy paste of link. the problem is link being updated but it is being updated after closing tag between  and

here is text input field

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" value="" name="nottitle99" id="title99" class="form-control"></div>
```

here is html for preview

```
     <div id="icon-small">                          
<img id="preview-title99" name="preview-title99" class="icon" src="square-icon.png">
     </div>
```

here is jquery

```
    $("input[id$=title99]").bind("change keyup input",function () {

 $("#preview-title99").prop("src","https://c.ndtvimg.com/2019-04/c4s53qqg_spicejet-shirdi-incident-ani-_625x300_29_April_19.jpg");

  });
   $("input[id$=title99]").keyup();
```

output i am getting is this

```
      <img id="preview-title99" name="preview-title99" class="icon" src="square-icon.png"> https://www.masala.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_slideshow_cache_734/public/images/2019/04/13/AnanyaPandey_0.jpg </img>
```

i want image src to be updated in src field

i tried several other things like

```
         $("#icon-small img").prop("src","https://www.masala.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_slideshow_cache_734/public/images/2019/04/13/AnanyaPandey_0.jpg");


     $("img#preview-title99").prop("src","https://www.masala.com/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_slideshow_cache_734/public/images/2019/04/13/AnanyaPandey_0.jpg");
```

any guide will be great

Comment: Have you tried closing your IMG tag: `<img id="preview-title99" name="preview-title99" class="icon" src="square-icon.png" />`

Comment: yes i tried not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Probably when you are trying to set the `src` attribute of image dynamically i.e. from an input, you are using `html` function of jquery or setting `innerHTML` property using the jQuery `prop` function because only that way, the image inner html is updating instead of src.

Here is a working js fiddle link which i made using your code. Anything you enter in the input will become the src of the image below the input: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaj5wc82/) .

Code inside fiddle in case link does not work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[id$=title99]").bind("change keyup input",function () {

             $("#preview-title99").prop("src",$(this).val());

              });
               $("input[id$=title99]").keyup();
    })


</script>

<div class="form-group">
  <input
    type="text"
    value=""
    name="nottitle99"
    id="title99"
    class="form-control"
  />
</div>

<div id="icon-small">
  <img
    id="preview-title99"
    name="preview-title99"
    class="icon"
    src="square-icon.png"
  />
</div>
```